# Error#285 The button Save is disabled, when Creating Payment and Applications Document in Acumatica 4.20.2115

Tags: acumatica

We are getting an error 'save button is disabled' while we try to create a new payment. we tried the same values and steps in UI which doesnt seems to have any issue. please support.

The webservice code is as below
Note: we have our class variables inside the code.

```
 foreach (Payment currPayment in order.InvPayments)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        paymentSchema = context.AR302000GetSchema();
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {
                                        BuisnessLogic.contextLogin();
                                        paymentSchema = context.AR302000GetSchema();
                                    }
                                    Command[] cmdPayment;
                                    paymentSchema.Actions.Insert.Commit = true;

                                    cmdPayment = new Command[]
                        {
                            paymentSchema.Actions.Insert,                            
                            new Value 
                            {
                                Value = order.CreatedOn.Value.ToLongDateString(),
                                LinkedCommand = paymentSchema.PaymentSummary.ApplicationDate,
                                Commit = true
                            },
                            new Value 
                            {
                                Value = order.interfaceStatus.InvoiceNbr,
                                LinkedCommand = paymentSchema.PaymentSummary.PaymentRef
                            }
                        };

                                    Command[] cmdBP = new Command[]
                            {
                                new Value 
                                { 
                                    Value = FirstOrder.CustomerID, 
                                    LinkedCommand = paymentSchema.PaymentSummary.Customer 
                                },
                            };
                                    cmdPayment = cmdPayment.Concat(cmdBP).ToArray();


                                    Command[] cmdHeader = new Command[]
                        {
                            new Value 
                            {
                                Value = currPayment.PayMethod, 
                                LinkedCommand = paymentSchema.PaymentSummary.PaymentMethod
                            },
                            new Value 
                            {
                                Value = currPayment.CashAccount,
                                LinkedCommand = paymentSchema.PaymentSummary.CashAccount
                            },
                            new Value 
                            {
                                Value = "false",
                                LinkedCommand = paymentSchema.PaymentSummary.Hold
                            }
                        };
                                    cmdPayment = cmdPayment.Concat(cmdHeader).ToArray();

                                    Command[] cmdINVDoc = new Command[]
                        {
                            new Value 
                            {
                                Value = currPayment.PayAmount.ToString(),
                                LinkedCommand = paymentSchema.PaymentSummary.PaymentAmount,
                                Commit = true
                            },
                            paymentSchema.DocumentsToApply.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
                            new Value 
                            {
                                Value = order.interfaceStatus.InvoiceNbr, 
                                LinkedCommand = paymentSchema.DocumentsToApply.ReferenceNbr, 
                                Commit = true 
                            },
                            paymentSchema.PaymentSummary.AppliedToDocuments,
                            paymentSchema.Actions.Save,
                            paymentSchema.PaymentSummary.Type,
                            paymentSchema.PaymentSummary.ReferenceNbr
                        };
                                    cmdPayment = cmdPayment.Concat(cmdINVDoc).ToArray();
                        //            var pay = context.AR302000Submit(cmdPayment)[0];


                        //            Command[] cmdSave = new Command[]
                        //{
                        //    paymentSchema.Actions.Save,
                        //    paymentSchema.PaymentSummary.Type,
                        //    paymentSchema.PaymentSummary.ReferenceNbr
                        //};

                                    //var payment2 = context.AR302000Submit(cmdSave)[0];
                                    var payment2 = context.AR302000Submit(cmdPayment)[0];

                                    string paymentType = payment2.PaymentSummary.Type.Value;
                                    currPayment.PaymentNbr = payment2.PaymentSummary.ReferenceNbr.Value;

                                    //release payment
                                    ReleasePayments(paymentType, currPayment.PaymentNbr);

                                    currPayment.Exported = true;
                                    currPayment.updateAsExported(BuisnessLogic.Reporter);
                                    BuisnessLogic.Reporter.writeLog("Invoice payment " + currPayment.PaymentNbr + " added.");
                                    //clear screen
                                //    cmdSave = new Command[]
                                //{
                                //    paymentSchema.Actions.Insert
                                //};
                                //    context.AR302000Submit(cmdSave);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    retval = false;
                                    ErrorMsg += "Invoice payment creation failed: " + //BuisnessLogic.getFriendlyError(ex.Message.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine;
                                }
                            }
```

DETAILED EXCEPTION

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> PX.Data.PXException: Error #285: The button Save is disabled.
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__c.MoveNext()
   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.CommitChanges(Object itemToBypass, PXFilterRow[] targetConditions)
   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()
   at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.Submit(String screenId, Command[] commands, SchemaMode schemaMode, PXGraph graph)
   at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Submit(String id, IEnumerable`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode)
   at PX.Api.Soap.Screen.ScreenGate.Submit(Command[] commands)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: One fact i realized is that, if you are creating payments in a sigle thread or one at a time, it seems working. If multiple threads keep creating documents for multiple invoices, it is not working. Acumatica might have to internally check what is going on inside.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on your observation that this works for one, single threaded, use case but not for multiple threads, I would be interested in seeing the code behind the management (creation and login, etc) for the "context" object (context.getschema() and

context.AR302000Submit(cmdPayment)

Each thread needs its own context!

Answer (score 0):

I've prepared template for you based on our demo data and version 4.20.2063, see below, it works fine on my side.

```
            context.Url = "http://localhost/AcumaticaDB_4_20_2063/Soap/AR302000.asmx";
        context.Login("admin", "123");

        Content AR302000 = context.GetSchema();
        context.Clear();

        AR302000.DocumentsToApply.DocumentType.Commit = false;
        try
        {
            Content[] AR302000Content = context.Submit(
                new Command[]
                            {   
                                new Value { Value = "Payment", LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.Type },
                                new Value { Value = "='new'", LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.ReferenceNbr },                            
                                new Value { Value = "ABARTENDE",  LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.Customer, Commit = true },
                                //new Value { Value = "DME", LinkedCommand = AR302000.FinancialDetailsLinkToGL.Branch, Commit = true },
                                new Value { Value = "CASH", LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.PaymentMethod, Commit = true },                                    
                                new Value { Value = "01/01/14",  LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.ApplicationDate },
                                new Value { Value = "101000",  LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.CashAccount },
                                new Value { Value = "false",  LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.Hold },
                                new Value { Value = "001",  LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.PaymentRef },
                                new Value { Value = "10496", LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.PaymentAmount },
                                new Value { Value = "test", LinkedCommand = AR302000.PaymentSummary.Description },

                                AR302000.DocumentsToApply.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
                                new Value {Value = "Invoice", LinkedCommand = AR302000.DocumentsToApply.DocumentType },
                                new Value {Value = "000709", LinkedCommand = AR302000.DocumentsToApply.ReferenceNbr },  

                                AR302000.Actions.Save,
                                AR302000.PaymentSummary.ReferenceNbr
                            }
            );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("RefNbr:" + AR302000.PaymentSummary.ReferenceNbr.Value);
```